# Use 我对你想说 or 我想说对你 to say: I want to talk/speak to you?

Tags: sentence-structure, phrase

It seems like when there is the word `对` in the sentence, you need to move noun/verb to the end of the sentence, but I am not sure. So here is my question. I want to say `I want to talk/speak to you`. Is it `我对你想说` or `我想说对你`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be 我想对你说

- 我想说 = I want to say
- 我想(对你)说 = I want to say (to you)

对 have to be placed before the object, and  [对 + object] have to be followed by a verb

想(want to) is the main verb, it is not moved to the end of the sentence

O Connor wrote:

> *Is it because of the word 对 that you need to move the second verb 说 to the end of the sentence?*

Not necessarily the end of the sentence, but [对 + object] need to be followed by a verb

- 我说 = I say
- 我(对你)说 = I say (to you)
- 我现在(对你)(说)明天的计划 = I now say (to you) tomorrow's plan

Comment: How to say: `I want to talk/speak to someone that did this to her`?

Comment: 我想 (对) (向她做出這種事的人) 说;  "向她做出這種事的人"  is the object

Comment: Is it because of the word `对` that you need to move the second verb `说` to the end of the sentence?

Comment: Not necessarily the end of the sentence, but [对 +object] has to be placed before a verb. 我说 -->  我(对你)说

Comment: If I want to add one more verb `走` or `去`. Where to put it in the sentence to say `I want to GO talk/speak to someone that did this to her`?

Comment: 我想 (去) (对) (向她做出這種事的人) 说